# gas now strategy doesn't work

Tags: contract-deployment, gas, python, smart-contract-wallets, brownie

When I'm using GasNowStrategy("fast") in my contract deployment I get an error:

```
    from brownie.network.gas.strategies import GasNowStrategy


def main():
    dev = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
    print(dev)
    print(network.show_active())
    deployed_contract = Bbum.deploy(
        {"from": dev, "gas_price": GasNowStrategy("fast")}
    )
```

What is the problem here?

**the error:**

```
  File "C:\Users\Omer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_brownie-1.17.2-py3.10.egg\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\Omer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_brownie-1.17.2-py3.10.egg\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\deployERC.py", line 9, in main
    deployed_contract = Bbum.deploy({"from": dev, "gas_price": GasNowStrategy("fast")})
  File "C:\Users\Omer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_brownie-1.17.2-py3.10.egg\brownie\network\contract.py", line 531, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "C:\Users\Omer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_brownie-1.17.2-py3.10.egg\brownie\network\account.py", line 510, in deploy
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "C:\Users\Omer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_brownie-1.17.2-py3.10.egg\brownie\network\account.py", line 727, in _make_transaction
    raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
  File "C:\Users\Omer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_brownie-1.17.2-py3.10.egg\brownie\exceptions.py", line 93, in __init__
    raise ValueError(str(exc)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I understood that GasNowStrategy has been shut down, it may be related to domestic regulatory policies. So if anyone encounters this issue, please change to other gas strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a personal fix, but you are going to have to emulate_fetch_gasnow and the strategies in network.gas.bases under a new script so you can change the endpoint.

Comment: do you have any reference about this?

Comment: I did fix it by going into the brownie package and looking at where it made a request to gasnow then retrofitting the ethgasstation api to it. This was a while ago and didn't submit a PR because that's a whole different process.